# Library Database Design

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship

Hi i've trying to design a library database.
Entities are

1. Book
2. Magazine
3. DVD
4. Member
5. Librarian
6. ...

   - Media types can be borrowed by members.Should i create 3 different
     loan tables for all media types or just one loan table.
   - if we think media as object , (book,magazine and dvd inherits
     media ) how can they expressed in E&R diagram.
   - If all copies of a book are borrowed,the book can be    reservable.I 
     can control it programatically(using select count(*) from books)
     but    i wonder if there is an efficient way to do this.

Comment: Homework? There's a "homework" tag for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use one loan table which includes a ref to other tables.
2. This link http://www.csc.liv.ac.uk/~valli/Comp507/slides23.pdf will
       be helpful for you.There is a sample.
3. You can create book table which has a column named total_quantity ,
       and another table book_copies.If a book is borrowed, you can
   update
       book.total_quatity--. When lending you can control whether 
       book.total_quantity is zero or not

Answer (score 0):

1. I would have one loan table that refers to a media (assuming 2) that is much easier to get totals etc.
2. Basically what you want in code is an extend, the book, magazine and dvd are all media. This is modeled by having a book with a reference to a media. To make a differentiation and link at the media you could add a refId, which refers to the book, magazine and dvd. And a enum ('BOOK', 'MAGAZINE', 'DVD') that tells to which it refers.
3. Probably the only moment you want to show this information is when you are checking out or information about the book is queried any way.

Comment: thanks for your reply but i cant understand how can i draw er diagram.How a relationship will be constructed  between media and book,magazine and dvd objects in er diagram.

Comment: As-far as I know you can't really model it. At least not in the editors I know.

Answer (score 0):

You should also think about adding new entity in the future. Say, library starts lending Kindles or iPads in the future? How would you accommodate these in the database? You will have to create new tables for each new entity which could be costly in terms of database performance.